# hipervinculos en php y js

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

hola buenos dias  estoy empezando a programar en php y js hasta ahora he hecho un **registro** en la bd en la **tabla talleres** el cual tiene cierta información como **nombre, edad, taller, direccion y descripcion**

e hice una tabla que solo me muestra nombre y el taller ... lo que me gustaría hacer es que a darle click en **"nombre taller"** me envie dentro de la misma pestaña del navegador a un archivo llamado **datostaller.php** y alli mostrar la informacion completa del taller que se registro  ... **los botones de solitar o elminar son de adornos por el momento, lei que el onclick que era para enviar a otra pg para mostrar dichos datos pero no vi el proceso** podrian porfavor ayudarme ?

este es mi codigo

```
<?php 

include ('basedatos/conexion.php');


  $results=$bd->query("SELECT * from taller ");


 ?>

  
  <table class="table table-bordered">
  <th scope="col" style="text-align:center"><label >Docente</label></th>
  <th scope="col" style="text-align:center"><label >Nombre Taller</label></th>
  <th scope="col" colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><label >Accion</label></th>



    </thead>
    <tbody> 
    
                     
          <?php 
          while ($ROWS=mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
            ?>

            <tr>
              <th scope="col" style="text-align:center">
              
                 <?php echo $ROWS['nombre_docente'];?>
              
              
              </th>
        

                           
                <th scope="col" style="text-align:center"><a href="#" onclick="mostrartaller()" id="<?php echo $ROWS['taller_id'];?>"><?php echo $ROWS['nombre_taller'];?></a>


              </th>

             

                    <th scope="col" style="text-align:center"> 

              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success solicitar" id= "<?=$ROWS['clases_id']?>"> Solicitar  </button>


     
</th>

<th scope="col" style="text-align:center">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">  Eliminar</button>

</th>

 <?php }

 } 
?>
                </tr>



               
          <!--/td-->



    
      


    <div id="regist_solicitud"></div>



.status{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
</style>
<body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es necesario para realizar el enlace que utilices onclick de Javascript, pues plantear un enlace GET para ir a la página datostaller.php

```html
<th scope="col" style="text-align:center">
  <a href="datostaller.php?id=$ROWS['taller_id']" id="<?php echo $ROWS['taller_id'];?>"><?php echo $ROWS['nombre_taller'];?></a>
</th>
```

Posteriormente en el fichero datostaller.php capturas el parametro id del GET, entiendo que el id del taller es un entero.

```html
$id_taller = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
```

Y ya con $id_taller capturado, consultas la BBDD para obtener los datos que quieres mostrar.

Comment: <a href="datostaller.php?id=$ROWS['taller_id']"     en este ROWS['taller_id'] no me trae el id  muestra exactamente eso ... id=$ROWS['taller_id']

Comment: Solo habría que hacer `echo` de la variable: `<?php eco $ROWS['taller_id']; ?>`